# Function returning a structure and function returning a string-- Different behaviour?

Tags: string, function, structure, local

I have heard that we cannot return a pointer to a local (automatic) array variable from a function since the automatic variable have limited scope and they die off once the called function returns.

```
char *s getName()
{
char name[]="Sumit";  // Automatic variable 
retrun name; // No scope outside the function

}
```

But a doubt arises in my mind:

```
struct info getInfo(int a,int b)
{

struct info f1; // Automatic variable memory allocated for a structure
f1.a=a; 
f1.b=b;

return f1;

}
```

here also we are returning a reference to a memory location which is allocated locally. Then how come here it works perfectly fine.

PLZ HELP
Waiting for reply

Comment: How is `getInfo` returning a pointer?

Comment: getInfo() is not returning a pointer. It is returning a structure.My question is how come memory allocated for the string vanishes after the function returns while the reverse happens for the structure, it is retained and is availbale to the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're "actually" returning 2 ints (well not quite, but follow the analogy).

It's the same reason why

```
inline int GetZero (int i)
{
    int j = i;

    return j;
}

GetZero(0);
```

works...

Also, you are not returning a reference, you are returning values.

THIS is returning by reference:

```
int& GetZero (int i)
```

And obviously this is returning by pointer:

```
int* GetZero (int i)
```